# Generic issue in swift

Tags: generics, swift

I have defined a protocol like this:

```
public protocol JSONConvertible {
    typealias T

    class func fromDictionary(dict: NSDictionary) -> T?
    class func fromArray(arr: NSArray) -> Array<T>
}
```

fromDictionary will convert dictionary to object, for example User, and fromArray will make use of fromDictionary to convert NSArray to Array.

What I wanna do is to provide a BasicObject, which provide default implementation for fromArray, sth like:

```
public class BasicObject<T>: JSONConvertible {

    public class func fromDictionary(dict: NSDictionary) -> T? {
        return nil
    }

    public class func fromArray(arr: NSArray) -> Array<T> {
        var result = Array<T>()

        for obj in arr {
            if let object: T = self.fromDictionary(obj as NSDictionary) {
                result.append(object)
            }
        }

        return result
    }

}
```

Then User class will inherit from the BasicObject.

However when I do this like in Java, it tells me the class must be generic as well:

```
public class User: BasicObject<User> {}
```

Then the code becomes:

```
public class User<User>: BasicObject<User> {}
```

First this looks weird, secondly when I init an object it would be:

```
var user = User<User>()
```

And cannot pass the compilation (error: cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers).

So what shall I do to achieve my purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the error was because I was initing it in test case and the init() was not public.

```
Also User<User> can be anything like User<Int>()
```

There is typealias solution like:

```
typealias user = User<Int>
```

then you can init your object with:

```
user()

However the User<Int> brings unnecessary <Int> and it looks really weird.
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are as follows:

```
protocol JSONConvertible {
    class func fromDictionary(dict: NSDictionary) -> Self?
}

func objectsFromArray<T: JSONConvertible>(arr: NSArray) -> [T] {
    var result = [T]()
    for elem in arr {
        let dict = elem as NSDictionary
        if let obj = T.fromDictionary(dict) {
            result.append(obj)
        }
    }
    return result
}

class User: JSONConvertible {
    class func fromDictionary(dict: NSDictionary) -> Self? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

1. The `fromDictionary` method should return `Self?`, as shown.
2. Don't bother putting `fromArray` into your protocol. Due to limitations in Swift's generics, returning `[Self]` doesn't really work well. (Try it and you'll discover why.) Because of this, I've made `fromArray` a global function called `objectsFromArray`. If this seems jarring to you coming from the world of Java, keep in mind that Swift has many global functions that work on generics, such as `contains`, `prefix`, `join`, etc. They are global functions rather than methods because of certain limitations in Swift's type system.
3. Don't bother creating a base class. I know this is your instinct from Java, and it's mine too coming from C#, but it doesn't work well here.